# Borel equivalence relations in models of determinacy

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, descriptive-set-theory

The following appears as fact 3.1 in the [slides](http://logic.berkeley.edu/Tarski/tarski-lectures-hjorth.pdf) from Hjorth's 2010 Tarski Lectures. Assume ${L(\mathbb R)} \models \mathrm{AD}$.

> **Fact 3.1** For E and F Borel equivalence relations one has
>   $$E \leq_{L(\mathbb R)} F$$
>   if and only if
>   $$|\mathbb R/E|_{L(\mathbb R)}  \leq |\mathbb R /F|_{L(\mathbb R)}.$$

My understanding is that the first inequality is a reduction via a function in ${L(\mathbb R)}$, and the second inequality is a comparison of cardinalities within ${L(\mathbb R)}$. What is the proof of this result? I am particularly interested in whether this result holds in the Chang model, assuming convenient large cardinal axioms.

Comment: Isn't it ever so slightly easier to say "work in $L(\Bbb R)$ ..." and then just omit the $L(\Bbb R)$ and all the continuing references to which model these things are computed in?

Comment: I think the first reducibility should be Borel reducibility. Otherwise it would be a simple tautology.

Comment: @YizhengZhu: I think that the statement is not a simple tautology, due to choice issues.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I copied the statement exactly as it appears in the slides, because I am not completely confident of the meaning of this notation.

Comment: Oh, I'm not criticizing you. Just generally complaining about notation. :)

Comment: The statement has a typo. He has not defined $\le_{L (\mathbb R)} $. The second inequality is awkwardly written, but it is his notational convention to indicate that there is an injection in $L (\mathbb R) $ from one quotient to the other (but this is the standard definition of $\le_{L (\mathbb R)} $). Presumably he meant to write that $\mathsf{AD} $ proves that there is an injection between the quotients constructible from $\mathbb R $ iff there is Borel injection.